# Inserting variables in database in php + mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I'm totally PHP beginner, and I'm trying to insert variables in a database in PHP and MySQL.
This is my code:

```
$link = mysql_connect('localhost','','','onlynews') or die('Cannot connect to the DB');
mysql_select_db('TEST',$link) or die('Cannot select the DB');

$strSQL = "INSERT INTO news(id, title,photo,url,source, at) VALUES('$x','$title','$url','$imgurl ','$source','$at')"; 

mysql_query($strSQL) or die(mysql_error());
```

The problem is it is doing: NOTHING! No Entries at all, Nothing changes in the database.

-How can I fix this?

-Do I have to write codes to prevent SQL Injection, even if the variables are coming from an API, not from users?

Comment: You're just setting $sql to a string. You need to actually execute the query as well using mysqli. You should also look into preparing the query / using parameterized queries so you're safe from sql injection hacks. Concatenating values directly into the query string is very unsafe.

Comment: I've edited the post, please read it for updates.

Comment: Do you have error reporting turned on in your local development environment? which php version are you using? All mysql_* functions are removed in PHP 7 so that might be it

Comment: Yes, that was the problem, thank you, it worked!

Comment: But do I have to write codes to prevent SQL Injection, even if the variables are coming from an API, not from users?

Comment: Could you explain in more detail, how you obtain the values of your variables, e.g., `$title`? How is that API interacting with the PHP script? If there is any chance, that someone can influence the values of these variables (and `$title` sounds like a user-specified value), how do you ensure that there is no quote in `$title`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to execute your query using [`$conn->query($sql);`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php).

However, to avoid SQL injections you should definitely use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or at least [`$conn->real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) to escape the values in your SQL statement.

For example, this is your code using prepared statements:

```
 $servername = "localhost";
 $username = "";
 $password = "";
 $dbname = "onlynews";
 $tableName = "news";
 $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
 $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO news (id, title, photo, url, source, at)
                         VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
 $stmt->bind_param('ssssss', $thetitle, $urlToImage, $theurl, $thesource, $thetime);
 $stmt->execute();
 $stmt->close();
```

You should also add some error checking, since `$conn->prepare()` and `$stmt->execute()` may fail (and return `false`). Of course, establishing the connection to the database during the construction of `$conn` could also fail, which can be checked using `$conn->connect_error`.